# Batch script to create folder with permissions

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I need a batch file able to create the following folders on a windows XP system with read/write permissions:

/Documents and Settings/John/Local Settings/Temp/Folder1/Folder

- The file may need to check if the folder already exists. Not sure how the batch file would react if the folders are already there.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir "/Documents and Settings/John/Local Settings/Temp/Folder1/Folder"
```

if the folder exists, it will not be created

i'm not sure for xp, but generally in windows for permissions you can use `cacls` (deprecated) or `icacls` commands, which are actually `.exe` files located in `C:\Windows\System32\`

Comment: there are also `set-acl` and `get-acl` commands in powershell that can set and get permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `attrib` command. That should have everything you're looking for.